# How do I use my Ubuntu machine as a bridge to allow an old XP machine internet access?

Tags: wireless, windows-xp

My ubuntu box is connected to the home network with a G wireless card.  My wife wants internet access with an old XP machine for light email and a typing program that links to a database for progress reports.  Again, I assume that is light use.  Can I bridge her XP machine through my ubuntu (wired connection between NIC's - they are 4 feet apart)  If so, HOW do I do this?

|DSL| -> Wireless -> |Ubuntu|(good connection) ==O==O== wired -> |XP|

Yes, I know I could buy a wireless card for the XP, but I'm cheap, OK!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link, You have to do masquerade.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/sharing-internet-connection-in-ubuntu.html

Hope it helps.